# XSS Attack security in webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, xss

I have created a asp.net webforms application. I am blocking the users to submit any script. For that I have implemented the ValidateRequest=true in the page section and in the web.config as well, which works fine when i try to submit any XSS data from controls like from a textbox.

It shows me the error which is fine

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$cphIllustration$ucClientData$mini_li_txtFirstName="testtest").

But when i am trying to submit the request using **Fiddler** then it is submitting the data to the server. Without showing any error.

[image]

> If someone is going to use the fiddler then he can easily submit the
> script, please advise what is need to do so that i can restrict the
> user to do so.

Thanks

Comment: You should always html encode user input before displaying. By user input I mean anything dynamic - from database, from what user typed, from cookie values, from local storage... anything.

Comment: i have to implement the security in a big project, which will take so much of time an effort to do so. I want a quick solution which can be handled centrally.

Comment: There are no shortcuts, unless you just stop accepting input.